Differentiability of mapping similar to distance function
Let us consider some convex, bounded, and closed (i.e. convex and compact) set $A\subset{R}^m$, where $m\in\mathbb{N}$. Further, we consider the following mapping
$$x\mapsto \inf\{s\geq 1: x\in sE\}.$$
This function is somewhat similar to the distance function, so I was wondering if there actually is a name for it in the literature? Moreover, I am interested whether the function is differentiable (at least outside of $A$, so if we stay away from the boundary $\partial A$). I would be very thankful for any references and answers!

This seems to be related to the Minkowski functional (sometimes also named gauge functional).

Thank you, that certainly helps!
